# Change properties/preferences of other eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, preferences

I'm working on an eclipse plugin that extends an existing plugin. The plugin I am extending defines some default preferences which can be changed at runtime via the preferences menu. I want to have some of those properties changed for the users of my plugin.
For instance: A property in the plugin I'm extending exists that isn't checked (i.e. false). I want it to be checked for my plugin by default.
How can I do that?

Not a duplicate of [Can my Eclipse plugin change preferences from other plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587572/can-my-eclipse-plugin-change-preferences-from-other-plugins), because that question aimed at creating a new prefence page that changes other plugin's preferences (as far as I understood it). I don't want to create a new preference page, I simply want to change the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the plug-in ID and the preference name, but then the following code should do the trick:

```
IPreferenceStore s = new ScopedPreferenceStore(new InstanceScope(), "org.eclipse.ui");

ss.setValue("SHOW_MEMORY_MONITOR", true);
```

This exact code will enable the memory monitor in the status bar...

Comment: At your own risk. This is not a good practise to do this. One plug-in should not meddle with other plug-ins private data. What if your host plug-in removes/modifies its preference, that will break your plug-in.

Comment: I guess this might work, but
a) where in my plugin would I used that code? In the Activator?
b) When I put that code in the Activator, the settings were applied (that is, the appropriate box in the preferences dialog was checked), but they didn't become effective until I manually applied them from the preferences dialog.

Comment: @Ankur I do not agree! This is the accepted way to change published preferences. Of cause, you should not change anything private...

Comment: @Malhelo This should not be necessary! I have done this in a number of  customer projects - usually for RCP applications in the `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` but also in a designated plug-in (just remember to add the `startup` extension point to ensure the plug-in is started!).

Comment: So, do I get that right: One possibility is to create some class `PreferenceSetter extends WorkbenchAdvisor` (for me, there is no class ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor) that changes the preferences for me?
I created such a class, but how do I tell my plugin to activate it? I couldn't find an extension point that sounded like what I need...

Comment: There are exactly one `WorkbenchAdvisor` sub-class for each Eclipse based application. I guess, you're running inside the IDE, so you'll need a new plug-in that will do just this..

Comment: I still don't really understand... Now I created an separate plugin just for setting the preferences and created a `PreferenceSetter extends WorkbenchAdvisor` in it. In that PreferenceSetter I implemented the method `initialize()`. I also added the startup extension to said plugin. But how does the PreferenceSetter become active? I am not supposed to call said `initialize()` method, am I?

Comment: Ohh.. The `WorkbenchAdvisor` is just for RCP applications. You can just add the code fragment above to `Activator.start(...)`.

Comment: Ok, still thanks. If I add the code snippet above in Activator.start() the settings will be applied. However, they will not become active until I go to the preferences dialog and press "Apply" or "Ok". I guess I can live with that...